# How to fix out the error dpkg: error processing colord (--configure):

Tags: 12.04

I have upgrade my ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.04. at last i can found that when i tries to install some packages it shows a error.
 after reading some blog i tried to fix that error by "sudo dpkg --configure -a". but when i run this command it show another error this

```
Setting up colord (0.1.16-2) ...
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
adduser: `/usr/sbin/useradd -d /var/lib/colord -g colord -s /bin/false -u 115 colord' returned error code 1. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing colord (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up whoopsie (0.1.32) ...
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
adduser: `/usr/sbin/useradd -d /nonexistent -g whoopsie -s /bin/false -u 115 whoopsie' returned error code 1. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing whoopsie (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up lightdm (1.2.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Adding system user `lightdm' (UID 115) ...
Adding new user `lightdm' (UID 115) with group `lightdm' ...
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
adduser: `/usr/sbin/useradd -d /var/lib/lightdm -g lightdm -s /bin/false -u 115 lightdm' returned error code 1. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing lightdm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on lightdm; however:
  Package lightdm is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 colord
 whoopsie
 lightdm
 ubuntu-desktop
```

what can i do now ?

Comment: Can you try this again: `sudo /usr/sbin/useradd -d /var/lib/colord -g colord -s /bin/false -u 115 colord`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[ -f /etc/gshadow.lock ] && sudo rm /etc/gshadow.lock
[ -f /etc/shadow.lock ] && sudo rm /etc/shadow.lock
[ -f /etc/passwd.lock ] && sudo rm /etc/passwd.lock
[ -f /etc/group.lock ] && sudo rm /etc/group.lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 4):

This fixes it for me:

```
sudo delgroup scanner  
sudo apt-get install colord
```

That did it for me.  Below were the diagnostic steps I took.

if you look at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/colord.postinst` - and add a `set -x` at the top and run it manually (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/colord.postinst configure`) - it will not get past adding the scanner, and if you get rid of `--quiet`, it says:

```
sudo addgroup --system scanner  
addgroup: The group `scanner' already exists and is not a system group. Exiting.
```

Comment: Ugh... the formatting here removed a critical CRLF...

the fix is:

sudo delgroup scanner; sudo apt-get install colord